# How can I avoid this pitfall in my Prolog recursion?

Tags: recursion, prolog

My objective is to be able to traverse nodes in a diagram and output the length of the path in Prolog. I'm using recursion and I'm stuck on this issue. Here's my attempt so far.

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(a,d).
edge(d,f).

distance(X,Y,1) :- edge(X,Y).
distance(X,Y,Dis) :- edge(X,Z), distance(Z, Y, D), Dis is D +1.
```

Issue: I'd like to be able to say Dis = 0. if the path is invalid. As in, there is no edge connecting the two nodes, Dis = 0. Currently my code says false for an invalid path. My attempts in this endeavor have lead to me breaking the recursion. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure about the semantics of distance? Wouldn't Dis = 0 imply that the two nodes are the same? This could be coded as distance(X,X,0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Hashcut says in his comment, it would make more sense that if `Dis = 0`, then `X = Y`. It is in fact perfectly logical that your predicate would fail if the path is invalid.

Now if you really want to do what you say, you can do it as such:

```
distance_(X,Y,1) :- edge(X,Y).
distance_(X,Y,Dis) :- edge(X,Z), distance_(Z, Y, D), Dis is D + 1.

distance(X,Y,D) :- distance_(X,Y,D) -> true ; D = 0.
```

We simply rename your original predicate into `distance_`, and then create the predicate `distance` which does the same as before if the path exists, or unify `D` with `0` if it fails. `->` is used to discard the choice `D = 0` if the path is valid.

Note that you have this behavior:

```
?- distance(a,a,X).
X = 0.

?- distance(b,f,X).
X = 0.
```

Which is kind of weird, but expected because of what you want.